# Understanding the "vertical shift" property of big Oh

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So I have difficulty understanding the big Oh property that says that if $\epsilon$ is some constant and  $\epsilon < f$ on a neighborhood of infinity, then $\alpha + f = \mathcal{O}(f) $ . I have trouble understanding why that is true.

Comment: I can't follow what you're saying; in particular, what are $f$ and $F$? Are you saying "if there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f>\varepsilon$ on a neighborhood infinity, then $\alpha+f=O(f)$"? If so that's easy, check that $C=\frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon}+1$ works.

Comment: Let me clarify by using latex in the question to properly convey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a< a C f \text{ for some constant } C>0$$

since we consider $f$ to be a positive function.

Thus $a+f\leq aCf+f \in O(f)$.